# Why my stylesheet won´t load into my node/add forms? (D6)

Tags: 6, theming

I wanted to have a special template for all my node/add forms, in my Drupal 6 installation.

So, I´ve added this code to a little module:

```
function modding_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if ((arg(0) == 'node') && (arg(1) == 'add')) {
    $vars['template_files'][] =  'node-add';
  }
}
```

My `node-add.tpl.php` template looks like this:

```
<h1><?php print $title ?></h1>
<?php print $content ?>
```

The thing is that **all styling has gone**.

The style sheets won´t load, and I don´t understand why. It looks as ugly as it can get when no style whatsoever is loaded.

I may add that **I´ve cleared cache more than once, and as this is a testing site, all performance caching has been disabled**.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve found the solution:

```
<?php 
      if ((arg(0) == 'node') && (arg(1) == 'add') || (arg(2) == 'edit')){
    $node = node_load(array('nid' => arg(1)));
    print $title;
    }
?>
```

[Thanks to nevets](http://drupal.org/node/1846094), who gave me the hint that I needed! :)